# Feed Item of type TrackedChange replies missing in query

Tags: soql, feeditem

I'm doing some work around feeditem and noticed that when a user replies to a post where the type is `TrackedChange` i'm not able to find this reply on workbench SOQL Query.  I find the original tracked change post but the reply seems to be missing.  How can I get this data in a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reply to the `FeedTrackedChange` is stored in a different `sObject`, a `FeedComment`. Both of these are children of a `FeedItem` (related to a specific sObject). Have a look at the ERD and I think it will be perfectly clear.

[image]